# Neo4j as a search engine

Tags: search, elasticsearch, graph, neo4j, full-text-search

I did several tests and read a lot of cases to use `Neo4J` for Graph-Based Search. I am convinced by the features as the flexible schema and Real-time search and retrieval. But I also realise it is not designed to store documents to facilitate full-text search. For me the potential of this product is in the business value through data relationships.

The product is matching for 99% with my case: a 'internal google' for the company where I work, except for full-text search on documents (Word, PDF, etc). This is not a hard requirement, but a nice to have. Nevertheless, should I drop the specific Neo4J features and go for a product like Elastic Search or is Neo4J the product we are looking for?

Comment: Also you should know that ES 2.3 now features a graph engine as well, which makes Neo4J almost obsolete for many use cases: https://www.elastic.co/products/graph

Comment: @Val The ES graph features seem pretty limited (no index free adjacency - which is important for performance of complex graph traversals and no property graph model).

Comment: True, Will, I was just pointing out that for "many simple use cases", ES would be able to fill a gap that wasn't possible earlier. Agreed it's still limited, but it will only get better. +1 for your answer ;)

Comment: ES graph has different goals. Simple query language. Relevance-ranking for nodes. Aggregate edges. "Elastic" compute clusters. Traversal does use some O(1) data structures but we don't use this everywhere because index-free adjacency at query time never comes for free  - it must be paid for with every write.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options for text search in Neo4j:

Cypher (the Neo4j query language) includes a few string comparison operators: `CONTAINS`, `STARTS WITH` and `ENDS WITH`. For example:

```
MATCH (d:Document) WHERE d.title STARTS WITH "Graph"
RETURN d
```

You can also make use of Lucene queries with Neo4j through "legacy" indexes. For example:

```
START doc=node:node_auto_index("title:graph*")
...
```

See [this post](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) for more information.

You can also model documents as graphs, and query them using Cypher as a graph model. For example, see the [Neo4j Doc Manager project](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager) for converting data from MongoDB to Neo4j.

Finally, you can also use Neo4j and Elasticsearch together, indexing text data in Elasticsearch and using Neo4j for graph traversals. See [this project](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. With 'documents' for full-text search I am refering to Word and PDF documents.